# Wrap HTML Elements around a Table (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, grid

I don't think this is possible with base bootstrap, but that is the css framework I am using. I am using bootstrap columns, but if there is a way to do this without them, that would be fine.

Basically I have 2 columns. The column on the right should be auto height to the Table. It only ever contain a table, but the table can contain, text images, etc.

Then the column on the left should contain all elements until they reach the height of the right table, then they should wrap underneath the table.

What I am trying to achieve:
[image: Showing the Intended effect I want]

An example of a website that has this effect:
[image]
[Link to site example](https://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/Bullet_King)

```
<div class ="row">
    <div class ="col-md-8">
    //elements here like images, headers, lists, etc
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-4">
    //table here
        <table class ="table table-bordered">
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class ="row">
    <div class ="col-md-12">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can still float elements with `.float-right` for example

Comment: ... totally forgot about floats. Thanks, I feel dumb. One issue though, after applying that to my table. I have a background color on left elements that’s overlapping with right float..

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided your CSS so I used the default bootstrap CSS file:

Here is the restructured HTML/CSS:

```css
.left-div {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #b2b2b2;
}

.content-div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: auto;
}

.table-div {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}

.table-bordered {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row special-row">
  <div class="col-md-12 left-div">
    <div class="content-div">
      <div class="table-div">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <p>//table here//table here//table here//table here//table here//table here//table here//table here</p>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="your-contents">
        <p>//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements
          here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here
          like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like
          images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images,
          headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers,
          lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists,
          etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc//elements here like images, headers, lists, etc</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  </div>
</div>
```